# grep command to extract a word

Tags: linux, grep

Here is my file.

```
    this is temp1
    this is temp2
    this is temp3
```

How to use grep command that while looking for pattern 'temp', the result should be displayes as only 'temp1, temp2, temp3', instead of whole sentences.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use -o option

```
$ grep -o "temp[0-9]"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.And what if I want to extract distinct words, in case I've duplicate words?

Comment: maybe you can use uniq command ... grep -o "temp[0-9]" | uniq

Answer (score 3):

You would probably want to use `grep` in combination with `sed`. sed uses perl-style regular expressions and gives you much more pattern matching power (well, in my opinion). This will get get exactly what you need:

```
grep temp yourFileName | sed -e "s/.*(temp[0-9]*).*/\1/"
```

But if you want more than just temp[number], you can match "temp" then continue matching until you hit a whitespace. This will do the trick:

```
grep temp yourFileName | sed -e "s/.*(temp[^ ]*).*/\1/"
```

You may also need to escape the brackets if this is on the command line:

```
grep temp yourFileName | sed -e "s/.*\(temp[^ ]*\).*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break the line multiple lines then feed that into grep e.g.

```
grep myword | tr ' ' '\n' | grep myword
```